# When I run "who am i" at a UNIX prompt, what does "tty" and "ttys" stand for?

Tags: unix

I know this is a simple question, I'm just curious.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TTY

Comment: I guess you've never had the "privilege" of using a real teletype attached to a remote server before...  :-)

Answer (score 2):

[Teletype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teletype).

When Unix was first developed, built-in displays for computers were quite rare. I/O was accomplished by sending characters to another device. The teletype was the oldest and most established of these devices.

Answer (score 2):

TeleTYpe (The S is "Serial").

Hint: Google is useful.